How to set a custom paper size to the print button of Crystal Report Viewer
I have created a custom page size (9x6). And I have set all the printer settings in the Windows Control Panel. I have set the default custom paper size (9x6) in the Printing Preferences and Printer Properties.
The problem is that when I hit the print button from Crystal Report Viewer, the printer's default paper size is reset from "9x6" to "Letter". Which does not change when printing from any other application like MS Work or Excel. The default paper size I have set is "9x6". So I want a solution. So that the print button of Crystal Report Viewer also comes with the default paper size set as "9x6". Like the print button of any other application like MS Work or Excel.
private void cmbbilltype_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)   
 {           
      try
      {                
         LoadReport();   
      }      
      catch (Exception ex)       
      {           
         MessageBox.Show("Error printing the report: " + ex.Message);
      }        
 }             
private void LoadReport()    
{            
       PrintingDataSet database = new PrintingDataSet();  
       database.ReadXmlSchema(DatabaseReport);
       ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument(); 
       rd.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\WithdrawalAdvice.rpt");  
       rd.Database.Tables["depositadvice"].SetDataSource(dt); 
       crvAdvicePrint.ReportSource = rd;   
}

I am using this type of code. But when report is loaded in CrystalReportViewer. Then custom paper size is not set in print button of Crystal Report Viewer.
